# What's the need of passing "this" as parameter to global - IIFE?

Tags: javascript, this

I had seen the pattern very often, I came across this line of code

https://github.com/addyosmani/timing.js/blob/master/timing.js#L122

```
(function(window) {
 ...
})(this); // <-- this
```

I always think it is redundant. Whats the need of passing the "this" to the IIFE ?

Comment: So that if you redefined `window` like `var window = foo`, it would still work.

Comment: By doing so you make sure that if the `window` object was overwritten it's restored back to `window`.

Answer (score 2):

By passing this in, you are explicitly forcing the parameter `window` to be localized in scope.

Technically, you don't need to do this, but by doing so, you are removing the necessity of accessing a global variable, in this case window. It's a good practice to be in because, the function isn't relying on the global object to be named `window`, or even be the window object at all.  Is this an outside case, yeah possibly depending on what you're building.  If you're building a framework for other people to use and possibly be used with other frameworks, all bets are off as to what might happen to the global objects which everything can access, so it's better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There are several reasons, including but not limited to:

- better for minification `(function(a){...})(window)`
- local variables seem to be faster at resolving (negligible)
- interop with nodejs where `window` doesn't exist, but `global` does
- redefined `window` global variable issue (as noted by @4castle)

Answer (score 0):

In linked code IIFE is [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode) function - and it's invocation happen outside of strict code - so `this` makes argument named `window` always refers to global object, regardless of environment (Node.js use `global` instead of `window`).

Some older browsers allowed to [shadow](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_shadowing) global property `window`, so accessing `window` could result in unexpected.

Answer (score 0):

Each function has its own `this` context. It won't automatically inherit the `this` from the parent, unless you specifically pass it as an argument or use `Function.prototype.bind()` (read more here https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind).

For this example it seems it doesn't really matter much since `window` is global, but in reality it's useful to enforce that IIFE should not use global variables, and you can also pass different contexts, let's say if you are writing unit tests and want to mock `window` so you would pass a fake object representing `window`.

Nevertheless your example would also work in Node.js since there is no `window` global object, but the `this` would evaluate to the root object

Answer (score 0):

By passing `this` you can control the object and it's properties  which you code can access.
By default `this` will map to `window` object so you can access it's properties. But you can also call this code from another function context  with similar properties and the code will still work thus giving you more flexibility.

Answer (score 0):

with global and scope in mind

my point of view

- `this` global object for the browser is `window` when between `<script></script>`
- `f{b{}}` is express different scope and `this` will take its role
- passing window object is isolation from pollution
- passing this as window is confusion for other (people and code) instead pass `window` directly

`(function(window){}(window))`